# Service inside a task? Or task inside a service

Tags: android, structure

I´m developing an android app with more people in my team, the app has services to make calls to remote apis and you have to make those calls with in a separate thread with Asynctask.

Now i have to make a new service, and looking through the previously ones done by my mates, i see that one of them instanced the service and inside the service created the AsyncTask, while the other mate instanced the service inside the AsyncTask.

So I was wondering, what is the best practice for this? Or are both ways correct and there is a specific reason for each way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Service inside the AsyncTask seems really weird!

It is most common to have AsyncTasks in the Service or Thread-Handler pattern so as to make sure you have the "background" thread for the communication calls.

But if the task of your service is just to perform a call to your remote API and then return results to the caller, I would strongly suggest to take a look at IntentService. The difference is that the IntentService does not need any AsyncTask in order to achieve this "background" (other thread) thing.

Check google doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Answer (score 1):

1. assuming you are saying Service which is the one in four Android components. a Service could only be instanced by Android system. you can not instance it in AsyncTask. if you instance service by java `new` keyword, the instance just perform like a normal Java class, out of the android system's control .
2. you can start a AsyncTask in service, it is a common design.

Comment: Im not using a Service component, called it a service just because is a Java class with methods that retrieve data from external apis so i can instance it anywhere.

Comment: so there is no problem new this `service` in AsyncTask. AsyncTask is used to do long blocking task.

Comment: Didn't have a problem, just wanted to know what was the best practice, because i saw it done either way in my project.